# jQuery autocomplete with Grails findByAll() array

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Hey guys thanks for the help in advance! I am trying to use grails findByAll() to pull a list into the jQuery autocompletion found here:https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I feel like I am getting close, but the use of grails in jQuery is throwing me off.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = "${fullSkillList?.name}";
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

The list that is printed out in html if I do a simple ${fullSkillList?.name} looks like [abc,cde,...,xyz] but the autocomplete won't work. Any suggestions? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can render the data as json, get & map it in javascript. The code below works that way and does the job. However, it is not a good way to tie autocomplete to a FindAll* method's return. Imagine if you had 100000 results. Anyway, an amateur snippet of what you need is below;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/stop/getStops",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                //Create a map.
                var data =
                        $.map(response, function (item) {
                            console.log("id: " + item.id);
                            console.log("name: " + item.name);
                            return {
                                id: item.id,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        });


                $("#from_tf").autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        console.log("from selected id:" + ui.item.id);
                        console.log("from selected name:" + ui.item.value);

                        $('#from_id').val(ui.item.id);
                    },
                    minLength: 3

                });

                $("#to_tf").autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        console.log("to selected id:" + ui.item.id);
                        console.log("to selected name:" + ui.item.value);

                        $('#to_id').val(ui.item.id);
                    },
                    minLength: 3
                });

            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the ${fullSkillList}

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        var availableTags = [ ];
        <g:each in="${fullSkillList}" var="eachSkill">
           availableTags.push("${eachSkill}");
        </g:each>
        console.log("tags: "+availableTags);
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

your controller can look like this:

```
def search(){
    def skills = Skills.list()
    def response = []
    skills.each{
        response << "${it.name}"
    }
    println("getAllSkills response: ${response}")
    render(view: "search", model: [fullSkillList: response])
}
```

However, this solution has the shortcoming of only loading (all data!) once.

Cheers!